# TS2345 error when manipulating array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Assuming I have an array which looks like that:

```
let arr = [{field: ["alice"]}, {field : ["bob", "charlie"]}
```

I want to be able to concat all values without writing the nested `for` loops.
I've done this so far:

```
arr.reduce((a, b) => a.field.concat(b.field))
```

The problem, as I see this, that the type of the array, lets say `arr : Array<MyObject>`, is changed when mapping or something similar.

Im getting a TS2345 error

> ...Is not assignable to parameter of type...

Just to clear things up, the result should be IDENTICAL to the following result.

```
let result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].field.length; j++) {
        result.push(arr[i].field[j])
    }
}
```

sorry I can't share my real code, but this is the exact issue.
This works on Chrome's developer tools for some reason but not when I try to compile my code.

Comment: Just to clarify, the for loop you've added is verified to work, right? The issue is just with TS compiling the reduce function to work the same way?

Comment: the loop works, yes. the problem is caused because after one concatanation the array[0] is a different type from the others so the next reduce call wont be type safe at all. by using Map before, we choose every items to be the desired type and then invoke a function on all of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const arr: Array<MyObject> = [{ field: ["alice"] }, { field: ["bob", "charlie"] }];

const result: Array<string> = arr.map(obj => obj.field)
                                 .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b));
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Well, the result is going to be:

```
["alice", "bob", "charlie"]
```

when I think you want:

```
[{fields: ["alice", "bob", "charlie"] }]
```

This would be calculated with:

```
[{ fields: arr.reduce((a, b) => a.field.concat(b.field)) }]
```

Comment: Well the point is the difference of having an array that's a list of names, vs an array containing one object, with one parameter "fields", which contains an array that's a list of names. Sorry, may have been something you already accounted for in code that's not shown.

Comment: lets say that the objects inside the array are models/classes.
I dont see how this works. Ive tried.